# MySQL date grouping

Tags: php, mysql

I have a financial transaction table in MySQL and am trying to produce a transaction report. Given the way the business operates, a financial day is 4am - 4am instead of midnight - midnight, so instead of grouping transactions by Y-m-d, I am having to consider all those transactions that happened after midnight.

For example:

The financial day is Monday 4am - Tuesday 4am. Any transactions that happened after Tuesday at midnight need to be classed in Monday's sales.

The premise of my query at the moment is:

```
select from_unixtime(date, '%Y-%m-%d') as t_date from transactions group by t_date
```

I've attempted using an if statement within the query to determine if the current row date is after midnight but before 4am, but to no avail. Hopefully, I can get this working in MySQL, without having to loop through all the transaction rows in PHP.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: use between query..Select column from table where date between '2014-09-21 04:00:00' and '2014-09-22 04:00:00'

Comment: You have to group by the statement: `from_unixtime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')` not `t_date`. You can access t_date if the query was in a sub query but since you're on the same level you have to use the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract 4 hours from the transaction time. Group by that value. MySQL has [date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) that help you with the subtraction.

Comment: Thanks, just seen the date_sub so I just minus a day if the hour is below 4

`if(from_unixtime(t.date, '%H') < 4, date_sub(from_unixtime(t.date, '%Y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL 1 DAY), from_unixtime(t.date, '%Y-%m-%d')) as t_date`

Comment: You can just subtract 4 hours from the database column before converting to other formats: `from_unixtime(date_sub(t.date, INTERVAL 4 HOUR), '%Y-%m-%d')`. Seems easier.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement to get yesterday record
Here is the query to handle this.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( t.date,  '%Y-%m-%d %k' ) as perDay 
FROM `table` t
WHERE t.date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 day) AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY perDay
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all transaction between Monday 4 AM to Tuesday 3 AM, then i think you need to check Date plus Time also like "Y-m-d h:i:s",

Comment: This is not an answer... it can be a comment.